# Computing rowMeans for every combination of columns

Tags: performance, combinatorics, r

The data:

```
    pre1 <-structure(list(A = c(0.0276, 0.0165, 0.0113, 0.0229, 0.0113, 
0.0151, 0.015, 0.0122, 0.0113, 0.0113, 0.0113, 0.0113), B = c(0.0884, 
0.0135, 0.0001, 0.0523, 0, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0007, 0, 0, 0, 0
), C = c(0.04, 0.0155, 0.0065, 0.0291, 0.0065, 0.0128, 0.0127, 
0.0078, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065), D = c(0.0897, 0.014, 
0.0001, 0.0546, 0, 0.0073, 0.0073, 0.0007, 0, 0, 0, 0), E = c(0.0911, 
0.0129, 0, 0.0537, 0, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0006, 0, 0, 0, 0), F = c(0.0891, 
0.0134, 0, 0.0529, 0, 0.0069, 0.007, 0.0006, 0, 0, 0, 0), G = c(0.0921, 
0.0118, 0, 0.0536, 0, 0.0035, 0.004, 0.0001, 0, 0, 0, 0), H = c(0.0906, 
0.0168, 0, 0.0631, 0, 0.0024, 0.0032, 0.0001, 0, 0, 0, 0), I = c(0.0922, 
0.0156, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0.0024, 0.0031, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), J = c(0.1115, 
0.0052, 0.0006, 0.0458, 0.0006, 0.005, 0.005, 0.0007, 0.0006, 
0.0006, 0.0006, 0.0006), K = c(0.0892, 0.0128, 0, 0.0514, 0, 
0.0073, 0.0072, 0.0006, 0, 0, 0, 0), L = c(0.0895, 0.009, 0.0002, 
0.0515, 0.0002, 0.0055, 0.0052, 0.0008, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002, 
0.0002), M = c(0.0887, 0.0135, 0.0001, 0.0525, 0, 0.0068, 0.0069, 
0.0007, 0, 0, 0, 0), N = c(0.0892, 0.0128, 0, 0.0514, 0, 0.0073, 
0.0072, 0.0006, 0, 0, 0, 0), O = c(0.087, 0.0133, 0.0001, 0.0511, 
0.0001, 0.0072, 0.0072, 0.0007, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001
), P = c(0.0875, 0.011, 0, 0.0492, 0, 0.002, 0.0027, 0.0002, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Q = c(0.0893, 0.0126, 0, 0.0518, 0, 0.0063, 0.0063, 
0.0004, 0, 0, 0, 0), R = c(0.0763, 0.0142, 0.0006, 0.0494, 0.0003, 
0.0018, 0.0027, 0.0007, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0002), S = c(0.0176, 
0.0173, 0.0172, 0.0175, 0.0172, 0.0173, 0.0172, 0.0172, 0.0172, 
0.0172, 0.0172, 0.0172)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", 
"S"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

obs<- c(0.0958964144767174, 0.00112749085522926, 0, 0.0538084597701149, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The list of column combinations:

```
library(foreach)
xcomb <- foreach(z=1:ncol(pre1), .combine=c) %do% { 
  combn(names(pre1), z, simplify=FALSE) }
```

The loop:

**CAUTION**

The following code takes 2 minutes to run on my PC (in fact, `pre1` has 23 columns and takes more than 37 minutes to run):

```
  library(plyr)
  res <- ldply(xcomb, function(l) {

  pred <- rowMeans(pre1[l])

  rmse <- sqrt(mean((obs-pred)^2))

  if(rmse<0.00345){
    me <- mean(obs-pred)
    smape <- sum(abs(pred-obs))/sum(pred+obs)
    data.frame(combin=paste(names(pre1[l]),collapse="-"),me = me, rmse = rmse, smape = smape)
  }

})
```

Example output of the reproducible:

> ```
>         combin            me        rmse      smape
> 1          J-L -0.0015764696 0.003398144 0.09119202
> 2          J-P -0.0011556362 0.003281430 0.08393609
> 3        E-J-L -0.0016195251 0.003424861 0.08216952
> 4        E-J-P -0.0013389696 0.003357466 0.07727013
> 5        F-J-P -0.0013000807 0.003448260 0.07759392
> 6        G-H-J -0.0018223029 0.003387601 0.06759025
> 7        G-I-J -0.0018111918 0.003316197 0.06720583
> 8        G-J-L -0.0014473029 0.003126429 0.07643285
> 9        G-J-P -0.0011667474 0.003091874 0.07144020
> 10       G-J-Q -0.0015584140 0.003436998 0.07965237
> 11       G-J-R -0.0010084140 0.003394027 0.08194241
> 12       H-J-L -0.0017556362 0.003236715 0.06739709
> 13       H-J-P -0.0014750807 0.003194667 0.06236702
> 14       I-J-L -0.0017445251 0.003162696 0.06825156
> 15       I-J-P -0.0014639696 0.003108024 0.06322841
> 16       I-J-R -0.0013056362 0.003443850 0.07335332
> 17       J-L-P -0.0011000807 0.003086438 0.07352729
> 18       J-L-Q -0.0014917474 0.003427897 0.08172932
> 19       J-L-R -0.0009417474 0.003443418 0.08960742
> 20       J-P-Q -0.0012111918 0.003384422 0.07680148
> 21     B-G-J-L -0.0014598029 0.003434496 0.07700107
> 22     B-G-J-P -0.0012493862 0.003418938 0.07643082
> 23     B-J-L-P -0.0011993862 0.003432305 0.08211289
> 24     D-G-J-L -0.0015618862 0.003446124 0.07491208
> 25     D-G-J-P -0.0013514696 0.003416486 0.07432744
> 26     D-J-L-P -0.0013014696 0.003417190 0.07998359
> 27     E-G-J-L -0.0015118862 0.003349091 0.07335527
> 28     E-G-J-P -0.0013014696 0.003321645 0.07178900
> 29     E-I-J-L -0.0017348029 0.003414617 0.06724261
> 30     E-I-J-P -0.0015243862 0.003377062 0.06548492
> 31     E-J-L-P -0.0012514696 0.003320299 0.07745106
> 32     F-G-J-L -0.0014827196 0.003419382 0.07576092
> 33     F-G-J-P -0.0012723029 0.003398932 0.07518129
> 34     F-I-J-P -0.0014952196 0.003443578 0.06884192
> 35     F-J-L-P -0.0012223029 0.003408147 0.08085604
> 36     G-H-J-L -0.0016139696 0.003264481 0.06225090
> 37     G-H-J-P -0.0014035529 0.003252500 0.06138754
> 38     G-I-J-L -0.0016056362 0.003192294 0.06289348
> 39     G-I-J-P -0.0013952196 0.003173631 0.05952244
> 40     G-J-K-L -0.0014535529 0.003434714 0.07694082
> 41     G-J-K-P -0.0012431362 0.003414584 0.07636996
> 42     G-J-L-M -0.0014681362 0.003426825 0.07650715
> 43     G-J-L-N -0.0014535529 0.003434714 0.07694082
> 44     G-J-L-P -0.0011223029 0.003097579 0.07148546
> 45     G-J-L-Q -0.0014160529 0.003354734 0.07485276
> 46     G-J-L-R -0.0010035529 0.003420185 0.08480000
> 47     G-J-M-P -0.0012577196 0.003410148 0.07593315
> 48     G-J-N-P -0.0012431362 0.003414584 0.07636996
> 49     G-J-P-Q -0.0012056362 0.003340910 0.07426441
> 50     H-J-L-P -0.0013535529 0.003183342 0.06700815
> 51     H-J-P-Q -0.0014368862 0.003449975 0.06977695
> 52     I-J-K-P -0.0014660529 0.003434489 0.07001368
> 53     I-J-L-P -0.0013452196 0.003103169 0.06514130
> 54     I-J-L-Q -0.0016389696 0.003392922 0.06855015
> 55     I-J-L-R -0.0012264696 0.003444943 0.07831468
> 56     I-J-N-P -0.0014660529 0.003434489 0.07001368
> 57     I-J-P-Q -0.0014285529 0.003368587 0.06791682
> 58     J-K-L-P -0.0011931362 0.003432281 0.08205326
> 59     J-L-M-P -0.0012077196 0.003421419 0.08161247
> 60     J-L-N-P -0.0011931362 0.003432281 0.08205326
> 61     J-L-P-Q -0.0011556362 0.003353159 0.07995181
> 62   B-G-J-L-P -0.0011973029 0.003415942 0.07979367
> 63   B-I-J-L-P -0.0013756362 0.003437632 0.07466828
> 64   D-G-J-L-P -0.0012789696 0.003409087 0.07809595
> 65   E-G-I-J-L -0.0016256362 0.003415821 0.06699637
> 66   E-G-I-J-P -0.0014573029 0.003398820 0.06648042
> 67   E-G-J-L-P -0.0012389696 0.003324390 0.07606610
> 68   E-H-J-L-P -0.0014239696 0.003427462 0.07246184
> 69   E-I-J-L-P -0.0014173029 0.003357870 0.07097378
> 70   F-G-J-L-P -0.0012156362 0.003397033 0.07878956
> 71   F-I-J-L-P -0.0013939696 0.003423666 0.07367445
> 72   G-H-J-L-P -0.0013206362 0.003251859 0.06770566
> 73   G-I-J-K-P -0.0014106362 0.003447292 0.07011274
> 74   G-I-J-L-P -0.0013139696 0.003181862 0.06621059
> 75   G-I-J-L-Q -0.0015489696 0.003404413 0.06893746
> 76   G-I-J-N-P -0.0014106362 0.003447292 0.07011274
> 77   G-I-J-P-Q -0.0013806362 0.003395895 0.06843233
> 78   G-J-K-L-P -0.0011923029 0.003408375 0.07974553
> 79   G-J-L-M-P -0.0012039696 0.003407449 0.07939387
> 80   G-J-L-N-P -0.0011923029 0.003408375 0.07974553
> 81   G-J-L-P-Q -0.0011623029 0.003347930 0.07806216
> 82   H-I-J-L-P -0.0014989696 0.003391859 0.06651120
> 83   H-J-L-P-Q -0.0013473029 0.003434350 0.07443353
> 84   I-J-K-L-P -0.0013706362 0.003419123 0.07461949
> 85   I-J-L-M-P -0.0013823029 0.003431058 0.07427245
> 86   I-J-L-N-P -0.0013706362 0.003419123 0.07461949
> 87   I-J-L-P-Q -0.0013406362 0.003363572 0.07294166
> 88 E-G-H-J-L-P -0.0013848029 0.003448137 0.07213946
> 89 E-G-I-J-L-P -0.0013792474 0.003387181 0.07089756
> 90 F-G-I-J-L-P -0.0013598029 0.003443722 0.07315096
> 91 G-H-I-J-L-P -0.0014473029 0.003420080 0.06695391
> 92 G-I-J-K-L-P -0.0013403585 0.003437713 0.07393901
> 93 G-I-J-L-N-P -0.0013403585 0.003437713 0.07393901
> 94 G-I-J-L-P-Q -0.0013153585 0.003392820 0.07253884
> ```

Comment: If your data set is numeric, using a `matrix` instead of `data.frame` should drastically increase performance. Also, `rowMeans` needs to convert to a matrix first anyway. Also, don't use `plyr` if performance is on stake. Finally, if you insist on a `data.frame`, `Reduce` will be much faster as it doesn't convert to matrix. Also. Can you add your desired output so we won't need to run your code?

Comment: I edited to include the desired output.

Comment: So you want to run this over ~500K column combinations?

Comment: ..and maybe more :-)

Comment: So your desired output are just selected column? Cause it should start with `A`, `B`, etc., no? Either way, a quick speedup should be converting `pre1 <- as.matrix(pre1)`, replacing the `data.frame(..` part with `cbind(..` (you should always try avoiding classes conversions/methods dispatching while optimizing code). And use `sapply` or `lapply` or a `for` loop instead of `ldply` (which probably also converts to a `data.frame`). A bit more complicated fix would be converting to a long format and trying to run this using `data.table`. Though your desired output is a bit confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled using matrix multiplication. Under the hood, matrix multiplication contains a for loop just like your code does, but it is a lot faster since it is all implemented in pre-compiled code.

So first compute a matrix of `0` and `1` where each row corresponds to a combination and each column corresponds to one of your `19` variables:

```
weightMatrix <- function(pre1) {
   nvars <- ncol(pre1)
   varnames <- colnames(pre1)
   wposs <- replicate(nvars, 0:1, simplify = FALSE)
   nposs <- Map(c, "", paste0("-",varnames))
   weights <- data.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, wposs))
   cnames  <- do.call(paste0, do.call(expand.grid, nposs))
   cnames  <- sub("^-", "", cnames)
   dimnames(weights) <- list(cnames, varnames)
   weights <- tail(weights, -1)
   return(weights)
}
```

Then your code translates to:

```
wmat <- weightMatrix(pre1)
pred  <- wmat %*% t(data.matrix(pre1)) / rowSums(wmat)
rmse  <- sqrt(colMeans((obs - t(pred)) ^ 2))
me    <- colMeans(obs - t(pred))
smape <- colSums(abs(t(pred) - obs)) / colSums(t(pred) + obs)

out <- data.frame(rmse, me, smape)
subset(out, rmse < 0.00345)
```

This code takes about 5~6 seconds on my machine with 19 variables. With 23 variables, it will have 16 times more combinations so it should still run in under 2 minutes. With many more variables, you will likely run out of memory trying to compute the weight matrix: you will have to adapt the code so it finds a good balance between memory usage and computation times.

Comment: Yes, your idea is very clever, but has the disadvantage that the pred table must be created in it's full dimensions before it gets filtered, which consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: For reference though, using `object.size`, your `xcomb` alone takes 305Mb, while my `wmat`, `pred` and `out` are only 75, 85, and 45Mb respectively.

Comment: However, when pre1 has 23 columns, your pred cannot be created on my pc (8 GB Ram).